# Slider in a draggable panel does not work in shiny 0.11

Tags: r, shiny

After updating to shiny 0.11 I'm having issues with sliders inside draggable panels. This is a simple ui.R that replicates the problem:

```
shinyUI(
  basicPage(
    absolutePanel(
    draggable = TRUE,
    wellPanel(  
      sliderInput("tst", h1("Testing slider"), 
                  min = 0, max = 100, value = 50, step = 1)
      )
    )
  )
)
```

The issue is that both the slider and the panel moves when dragging the sliders.
The slider essentially moves in relation to the moving panel - the movement is hence "doubled" on the slider. I'm also unable to release the slider, letting go of the mouse button only lets go of the panel dragging.

The above code worked fine in the previous shiny version. I know the slider was changed in 0.11, this seems to be a product of that.

Any thoughts on this?
Thanks!

Comment: I am not able to see a slider when I try to replicate your error and in stead am seeing a numeric input box, have you run into this?

Comment: Hi, and thanks for looking. No, I have not. Wen I run the above ui.R (together with an empty server.R) I get a slider that behaves as described above. Are you running shiny 0.11? I got a reply from the rstudio folks elsewhere and it seems this is a bug they will fix.

Comment: Whoops, looks like I'm running 0.10.2.2, but when I cleared out the `server.R` the panel worked as intended -- I was not able to replicate your error, maybe its a 0.11 bug.

Comment: Yes, looks like that's the case - this worked for me also in previous versions. And they did update the slider in 0.11...

Comment: This issue has been filed: https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/711